# How to email to HR manager who said she would get back to me but didn't?

Tags: human-resources, email

I requested from a HR Manager regarding new position openings at her company. I attached my with the email and I got following reply," Hi Rafhan, Let me check and get back to you." It seems like she has forgotten to reply me. So i want to email her again regarding that. Please guide me how to write the email.

Comment: Can you provide more details? How long have you been waiting for her reply? A day? A week? Longer?

Comment: I have been waiting for a week

Comment: proof read it before you send it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi XXX,
>
> I am writing to inquire whether there are any updates on available
>   openings at [insert company name]. I would like to reiterate my
>   interest in joining your company as a [insert occupation] because [insert a short reason], and I
>   believe that I have the requisite skills for such a role.
>
> Thank you for your time. Have a good day ahead!
>
> Best regards, 
>   Rafhan

**Key points:**

1. Do not appear pushy or impatient
2. Keep things short and direct
3. Emphasize your interest
4. Highlight your abilities
5. Be specific about the kind of roles you want, so that she won't waste time (both hers and yours) by sending you a whole catalogue of potentially irrelevant openings

If there is still no reply from her, forget about this company and move on.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Nameless, the answer above seems really great to me.

Do not forget to add your availabilities so as she could contact you whenever she wants. Be careful not to appear impatient is a really crucial point.

Do not be affread by not getting any reply within a week, she must have a lot of email and projects to follow on (such as everyone). It is not anormal. However it is a good thought to email her again in order to reaffirm your interest in the position. In doing so you will show your motivation and remind her of you both at the same time.